# Why do startup updates always fail on my computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

Windows 7 Home Premium asks me to shut down and install updates on every shut down.

When it boots up, it says "Configuring your updates... 0%" and after about five minutes it changes to "Failed update, rolling back."

I can't find anywhere to cancel these updates so that they don't run.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You might look in the System Event log for an error message.  Its could give us a clue as to what's happening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off updates:

```
Click Start, Choose Run.

In the Run box, type services.msc.

Click OK.

Right-click the Automatic Updates service.

Click Stop.
```

Then rename the “SoftwareDistribution” folder:

```
Click Start, click Run, type %systemroot%, and then click OK.
Right-click the SoftwareDistribution folder, and then click Rename.
Type SoftwareDistribution.old, and then press ENTER to rename this folder.
Create a new folder called "SoftwareDistribution"
Click Start. Choose Run.
In the Run box, type services.msc.
Click OK.
Right-click the Automatic Updates service.
Click Start.
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the [**Microsoft Fix it 50202**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058) tool from Microsoft's website.

It is compatible with Windows 7.