# Windows update configuration fails every boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-update, reboot

A few days ago Windows Update installed when I shut down my laptop.  When I restarted it hung at 0% for about 5 minutes.  Then it said reverting configuration and continued into Windows.  Now every time I shut down it down it reinstalls the updates, and every time I start the machine it hangs at 0% for a few minutes and reverts configuration.

What could be causing this?  My other machine installed and configured the same Windows Update no problem.

Here's the system specs:

- HP laptop
- Windows 7 Home Premium
  64-bit CPU and OS

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Why do startup updates always fail on my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/281206/windows-7-startup-updates-always-fail)

Comment: Well it hasn't happened since.  Hopefully it was just a fluke and reset some flag of some sort.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I had not yet installed SP1 and after I installed that the problem disappeared. I concluded that one of the updates was dependent on SP1 without handling or specifying this properly. Not sure if that also the problem in your case, but it's easy to try :-).